# replace duplicates in an array with new values from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to "flatten" an array that has multiple duplicate values. The array is created from a CSV that I'm then trying to run API requests on.
The format of the CSV is as follows:

```
Posts | Comments | 
post1   comment1
post1   comment2
post1   comment3
post2   comment1
post2   comment2
post2   comment3
```

I'm using Papaparse which returns:

`[{Post: 'post1', Comment: 'comment1'}, {Post: 'post1', Comment: 'comment2'}, ...]`

So I thought I would try to flatten them to where it would look like:

`[{Post: 'post1', {Comment: 'comment1'}, {Comment: 'comment2'}}]`

I tried using a `.map` and referencing the `index` to check if the previous `Post` was the same as the current `Post` if it is then `.push` to the previous index which I can't do using `.map`

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: This is not valid json. You can have a comments array for each object?

Comment: I don't need it to be valid JSON I just need it to where I can run requests on each object. My api returns a new ID for the created Post, which I need access to so that I can create the Comments. When they are in separate objects, it makes that very difficult to do.

Comment: Is this a good format? `[
  {
    "Post": "post1",
    "Comments": [
      "comment1",
      "comment2",
      "comment3"
   ] 
  } ... ]`

Comment: I can work with that ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the list while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `Post` is the key and the value is an object with `Post` and grouped `Comments` array for the `Post`
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), you can get a list of grouped objects

```js
const data = [ { Post: 'post1', Comment: 'comment1' }, { Post: 'post1', Comment: 'comment2' }, { Post: 'post1', Comment: 'comment3' }, { Post: 'post2', Comment: 'comment1' }, { Post: 'post2', Comment: 'comment2' }, { Post: 'post2', Comment: 'comment3' } ];

const res = [...
  data.reduce((map, { Post, Comment }) => {
    const { Comments = [] } = map.get(Post) ?? {};
    map.set(Post, { Post, Comments: [...Comments, Comment] });
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```